# Sending secure POST data to RESTful API without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, devise

I am working with an Arduino that I want to send data to a remote or local Rails RESTful API of mine. When building its front-end, I can login with devise and authenticate. But I am wondering what happens when you want a third party device to POST data to the backend ?

One choice could be to use random generated long hashes as keys, as Twitter does (a client key for example and an API key) which of course is not secure but decreases the chances someone will POST data easily to another account.

However, If I am right, the data will be sent over an http connection so they could be easily sniffed. There is no problem sending temperature data, but If someone decides to send RFID IDs and names etc. it could be a vulnerability.

How could I send data with a POST request to a RESTful Rails backend API:

1. authenticated?
2. secured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. authenticaed?

You will need an endpoint that the 3rd party can call (let's call him Zed). Zed sends a request (POST) to that endpoint with his email address. Devise then sends an email to Zed, with a confirmation link that contains a confirm_token. Zed clicks the link, which opens a page where he can enter a password. Once entered, he is logged in and an auth_token is stored against his user id. Subsequently he can use that auth_token to make further requests by passing the token in an Authorization header. The 'confirm_token' is throw away (you can set it to auto-expire after a given time period).

Obviously this requires Zed to manually create his account and login. Even if you setup a 3rd party 'developer program' you still need those developers to sign-up and generate tokens for them that they can pass in requests to your api. All of this should of course be done over https. Devise provides almost all of this capability out of the box.

2. secured?

HTTPS helps with the 'sniffing' aspect. The method above is secure, since only people who provide an email account they have access to can create accounts and get tokens that they can then user for later requests. However, you could use mobile phone number/sms as a second factor (google 2-factor authentication).

3. Without authenticaion - well, sort of

The only other option I can think of is that you issue known users a 'signing key'. They sign (encrypt) their request with this key. Since the key should only be known to them and can only be decrypted by the server using the matching public key, the data can be sent over HTTP. If anyone sniffs it, they almost certainly cannot crack the key to see what the real data is. All they can really do is mimic the request and keep sending that same request to the server repeatedly in a DOS attack.

But you still have to solve the problem of how do you verify WHO you are giving keys to - ie you still need to verify who Zed is somehow. Do you plan to do that offline and then email that 'verified' individual their private key? Using RoR, I still recommend sticking with Devise as most of the grunt work is done for you already.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, it answers most of my questions. What I am wondering is: 1. Is the devise functionality you are describing built in devise already (auth_token) ? I will definitely have everyone create an account and authenticate over devise. 2. If Zed has the auth_token, anyone that has his id (email/username for example) can POST data to the server, right ? 3. It might be a silly question because I've always used devise and Angular/Rails for APIs, but If I follow the (1) option, will the data be sent with a POST request over https or http ?

Comment: 1. Yes for normal use (ie users logging in and navigating your site in their browser). But to access the api directly I would recommend you add another gem (eg. an OAuth2 gem). 2. Not really, since you also need Zed's password to get the token created. 3. That is entirely server dependent - you have to install an SSL certificate on the server to have HTTPS working. This is well worth reading to get more detailed info on all this stuff: http://rubyjunky.com/authorization-and-authentication-in-a-Rails-api.html

Comment: 2. Yes, Zed will create it but the token will be a standard hash key, right ?

Comment: If Zed wants to POST data to the server over https, how will the certificate work ? I mean this requires the exchange of some session keys right? These are not exchanged over the POST request so how is it done ?

Comment: @ChrisV. yes the token is a standard hash key. No, HTTPS is just encryption of data between the server and the requestor, nothing to do with authentication or authorization. Adding an SSL cert to the server (and configuring it correctly) just ensures that all traffic is encrypted.

Comment: but the client doesn't need to get the certificate in order to connect ?